# SVG filter to make color image plain blue

Tags: css, svg, filter

I've been using `-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);` to make an image gray. Is it possible to tint the image blue? I thought I could possibly use and SVG filter and reference it in the CSS like this:

`-webkit-filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale);`

file filters.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <filter id="grayscale">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
 </filter>
</svg>
```

The above code is also just a greyscale filter and I don't know enough about SVG to make a blue one. The blue I am looking for is #002060.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
filter: hue-rotate(xxdeg); /* unprefixed */
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dD5SF/)

**HTML** (with raw image and filtered

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-200-200-8.jpg" alt="">

<img class="filtered" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-200-200-8.jpg" alt="">
```

**CSS** (with -webkit prefix only)

```
.filtered {
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

[**Useful Article**](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/functions/hue-rotate)

[**Useful Color Wheel**](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)

It looks like the rotate value you are looking for is 238deg but this may not have the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The hue-rotate filter gives different results for differently colored images. I figured out how to make a feColorMatrix for a specific color.

Comment: @MikhailJanowski ...and how, pray tell, did you do that? Would love to see your solution as an answer to this question.

Comment: The original example was disabled by JSFiddle, I've recreated it here: https://jsfiddle.net/a8e0gn9z/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use blend modes, their support is increasing:

(credit: CSS-tricks)

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-blend-mode/

[image]

And/or: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/monotone-image-css/